# Upload file to SharePoint using HTTP Client is not working

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, dotnet-httpclient

I want to upload a static file to SharePoint using Graph API and HTTP Client.
We have a folder where the file is kept, now we have to read the file from the folder and upload it to SharePoint.

```
Stream stream = GetFile() //this will return file data as a Stream.
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization
                     = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var streamContent = new StreamContent(stream);

var imageContent = new ByteArrayContent(streamContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result);
imageContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");
form.Add(imageContent, "Test.pdf");

var response = httpClient.PostAsync(@"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/lists/{folderName}/drive/root:/childFolder/Test.pdf:/createUploadSession", form).Result;
```

We are getting `BadRequest` response for the above request.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?msclkid=6b981ba1d04b11eca05e9aa8bdfcd4a4&view=graph-rest-1.0#request) no request body is required for `createUploadSession` endpoint but if you specify the body it must be json like this

```
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "item": {
    "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.driveItemUploadableProperties",
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename",
    "name": "largefile.dat"
  }
}
```

The response will contain `uploadSession` resource type.

To [upload the file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0#upload-bytes-to-the-upload-session), or a portion of the file, you need to make a PUT request to the `uploadUrl` value received in the `createUploadSession` response. You can upload the entire file, or split the file into multiple byte ranges, as long as the maximum bytes in any given request is less than 60 MiB.

Resources:

[driveItemUploadableProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitemuploadableproperties?view=graph-rest-1.0)

[uploadSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/uploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0)

[Upload bytes to the upload session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0#upload-bytes-to-the-upload-session)